# Time Machine doesn't backup folders with same name as user

Tags: macos, time-machine, backup

Let's say my OS X user's folder is called `Attila` and I have a folder with the same name in a folder, e.g. `~/Xcode/Attila/`. Now, if I do a Time Machine backup, the `~/Xcode/Attila/` folder won't be copied.

Why is it? Is there a workaround to fix this?

(OS X version: 10.8.3)

---

### EDIT

`tmutil removeexclusion` doesn't seem to work in this case:

[image]

---

### EDIT 2

Might not be relevant, but my user account was migrated from a Time Machine backup.

Comment: Are there other folders in ~/Xcode which do get backuped? What happens if you rename ~/Xcode/Attila and trigger a new backup?

Comment: Can you reproduce this in any other folder than ~/Xcode? I just tried with ~/temp/username and got `[Included] /Users/username/temp/username`.

Comment: @patrix: Renaming doesn't help. I've tried ignoring other folders, and removeexclusion doesn't seem to take any effect on either of them.

Comment: @lupincho: I'll give it a try when I'll be at home later today!

Comment: @lupincho: every folder that has the prefix "<username>" is excluded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a file called `Attila.sparsebundle` in my home directory. Renaming it to something that's not related to the username solved the issue.

Comment: Having a similar issue, TM is not backing up a path on an external volume named 'data'.   /Volumes/data/* is being backed up _except_ for /Volumes/data/home which isexcluded. Other than being named "home" there is nothing special about this folder or permissions compared to the other paths on the data volume. Removing the exclusion with tmutil does not change the reported state. There are no 'sparsebundle' files anywhere on the volume nor the boot volume. Yet, /Volumes/data/home is not being backedup.  Renaming the folder to e.g. 'homee' causes it to be not isexcluded.  WTF !? Yosemite 10.10.2

Comment: Turns out the "standard exclusions" include /home, /dev and /net on _all_ volumes, not only the boot volume. Oops. See /System/Library/CoreServices/backupd.bundle/Contents/Resources/StdExclusions.plist

Comment: @tribalvibes, thank you for pointing that out. I had a folder named "/Volumes/<apfs_container>/dev" for... you guessed it, development work, and it was getting excluded from backups.

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming you have already checked in in **System Preferences** > **Time Machine** > **Options** to ensure those folders have not been excluded?

We can then use the [`tmutil`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man8/tmutil.8.html) utility to find out some more information about this.

From **Terminal** enter this command:

```
tmutil isexcluded ~/Xcode/Attila
```

This will tell you whether it has been excluded from Time Machine backup or not. If it lists

```
[Excluded]    /Users/Attila/Xcode/Attila
```

You can then remove it from the exclusions list by running

```
sudo tmutil removeexclusion -p ~/Xcode/Attila
```

For more information on [`tmutil`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man8/tmutil.8.html), check out its [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man8/tmutil.8.html)

Comment: Pre-Mountain Lion will list an excluded item as `-    /Users/Attila/Xcode/Attila `

Comment: After `sudo tmutil removeexclusion -p ~/Xcode/Attila` the item is still in the list marked as `[Excluded]`, even when using `/Users/Attila/Xcode/Attila`. (Btw, running 10.8.3)

Comment: (I've added a screen capture to my question.)

Comment: Hmm... Well at least that does help us out. We know that time machine is actively ignoring it (rather than a bug). Try without the -p flag. Also, perhaps it's the Xcode folder that is excluded?

Comment: The Xcode folder is included. (No ignored folders are shown in System Preferences > Time Machine.). removeexclusion doesn't even work without the -p flag.

Answer (score 0):

Is FileVault or home folder encryption enabled?

Saw a mention of it at:

https://superuser.com/questions/53961/time-machine-no-longer-backs-up-changes-to-files-in-home-folder

If that is the case, then logging out of that account and into that of another user whose account isn't FileVault'd, you should be able to trigger TimeMachine and see the home account backed up.

Comment: FileVault is not enabled.

Comment: Hmm.. interesting. Going to try to simulate this on my other Mac tonight and see if I can't replicate the error.

Comment: @AttilaH btw, which version of Mac OS X are you using?

Comment: Mountain Lion 10.8.3 (It is included in the question...)

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: No, not yet. Strangely enough, couldn't find a blank disk I could use to test the time machine run on.